# How to post data from one rails app to another in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I have to post data from one rails app to another and get a response in return from the latter app to the former.Both are RESTFUL apps

my api to post data from the former app is as follows

```
 class OrderApiController < ApiController
    def send_invoice_data
        response = Hash.new
        result = Hash.new
        order = Order.includes(:status, :user, payment: 
                 [:status]).where(txnid: params[:txnid]).first
        if order
            if (['Notary', 'Attestation','Franking'].include? 
              order.service.name)
                no_of_copies = ((order.answers.where(question_id: 
               [37,15]).length > 0) ? order.answers.where(question_id: 
                [37,15]).first.body : 0).to_i 
            else
                no_of_copies = ((order.answers.where(question_id: 
                [37,15]).length > 0) ? order.answers.where(question_id:     
                [37,15]).first.body : 0).to_i + 1
            end
            result['order'] = {
                      id: order.id, 
                      txnid: order.txnid, 
                      service_name: order.service.name, 
                      :
                      :
                      discount: order.discount || '',
                      stamp_amount: order.stamp_amount || '',
                      delivery_amount: order.delivery_amount || '',
                      no_of_copies: no_of_copies
                      } 
            response.merge! ApiStatusList::OK
            response['result'] = result
        else
            response.merge! ApiStatusList::INVALID_REQUEST
        end
        render :json => response
    end

 end
```

The controller code for the latter app is as follows:

```
  class InvoiceApiController < ApiController

        def order_invoice
            response = Hash.new
            result = Hash.new
            debugger
            if params[:order] && params[:order][:txnid] 
                @order = params[:order]
                @order['stamp_amount'] = params[:order][:stamp_amount] || ''
                @order['txnid'] = params[:order][:txnid]
                @order['service_name'] = params[:order][:service_name] || ''
                @order['payment_date'] = params[:order][:payment_date]
                :
                :
                @order['discount'] =  params[:order][:discount] || ''
                @no_of_copies = params[:order][:no_of_copies]
                pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
                render_to_string(template: 
                'invoices/generate_invoice.pdf.erb', filename: params[:order]
                 [:txnid] + ".pdf" ,
                                type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 
                'attachment', print_media_type: true))
                save_path = Rails.root.join('pdfs', @order['txnid'] + ".pdf")
                File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
                  file << pdf
                  filename = @order['txnid'] + ".pdf"
                end
               file_name =  @order['txnid'] + ".pdf"
               upload = Invoice.upload(save_path, file_name)
               response['result'] = upload
               response.merge! ApiStatusList::OK
            else
                response.merge! ApiStatusList::INVALID_REQUEST
            end 
            render :json => response 

        end
```

The second app sends the link of the pdf generated invoice as response back to the former app.

The link for the later app would like this:

http://192.168.0.104:3000/api/v0/generate_invoice?key=value

How do I achive this. I am a rails novice quite new to RESTFUL api development as well.So please help with elaboration for the solution.

Comment: What is stopping you? You can use an HTTP library such as [this gem](https://github.com/httprb/http) to fire HTTP calls.

Comment: As an aside, you should really think about breaking down your controller and extracting logic into objects. It's quite difficult to read. At very least extract into private controller methods. You will not have a good time if you keep dumping stuff in a single method. If you can post this over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and send over a link I'll attempt to rewrite it for you in that way to give you an idea what I mean.

Comment: @31piy I used the httparty gem and managed to get the required result. Thank you

Comment: @DamienRoche  As per your suggestion, I've posted the code in codereview. Here is the link: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150684/rails-api-for-communication-between-two-rails-app-where-the-former-app-posts-dat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using Httparty gem. This what I did

```
 gem 'httparty'
```

in gemfile of both apps

```
bundle install
```

in console

The modified send_invoice method is below

```
 def send_invoice_data
    response = Hash.new
    result = Hash.new
    debugger
    order = Order.includes(:status, :user, payment: 
     [:status]).where(txnid: params[:txnid]).first
    if order
        if (['Notary', 'Attestation','Franking'].include? 
    order.service.name)
            no_of_copies = ((order.answers.where(question_id: 
         [37,15]).length > 0) ? order.answers.where(question_id: 
        [37,15]).first.body : 0).to_i 
        else
            no_of_copies = ((order.answers.where(question_id: 
            [37,15]).length > 0) ? order.answers.where(question_id: 
            [37,15]).first.body : 0).to_i + 1
        end
         response.merge! ApiStatusList::OK
         response = 
             HTTParty.post('http://localhost:3001/api/v0/generate_invoice?
             key=docket', :body => { "order" => {
                  "id" => order.id, 
                  "txnid" => order.txnid, 
                  "service_name" => order.service.name, 
                  "payment_date" => order.payment ?  
                   order.payment.created_at.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') : 
                   order.created_at.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), 
                            :
                            :
                  "delivery_amount" => order.delivery_amount || '',
                  "no_of_copies" => no_of_copies}}.to_json, :headers => { 
                 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
    else
        response.merge! ApiStatusList::INVALID_REQUEST
    end
    render :json => response
 end
```